# How can i show and hide the video player with Css buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Where can I find the code of the buttons after clicking on it show me a video or video player, but to be showing code iframe like this, for example, I mean press the button displays me the video player, and when I press the second button disappears the first player and displays the player in the second button

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N702W.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcdxD.png)

Comment: <iframe width='550' height='430' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen src='#'></iframe>

Comment: What have you done so far to achieve that ? Show us some code. You are looking for click events in JS and something called an <iframe>. What you want to do is to listen for the click event and based on that you show and hide some HTML elements like <iframe>